# How to keep API keys safe for deployment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I hope you are doing well!

There is a situation regarding API Keys and we are unsure how to handle it.

We are using Google Maps in our website and for that we are using an API Key from Google. However, since Google Maps is displayed on the frontend (ReactJS), it needs the key to be displayed. Whereas our backend needs it for reverse geocoding and geocoding API calls.

The situation is that we need the key to be stored safely, but also can be changed without a complete recompilation of our code.

Some cases:

1. Store it in the database and fetch it, but opening the Network Panel in the Browser Dev Tools and seeing a request being made shows the key returning in the response.
2. Storing it in React as well but people can have access to it if they search in the Applications Panel in the Browser Dev Tools.
3. Adding it to our .env file, but then is it completely safe if so? Can we access it after running `npm run build` and taking the build code?

How can we handle it with safety and keep it easy to change?

Thanks you for your time!

Comment: There is simply no way to hide anything that is delivered to the end user from them.
Regarding Google Maps: you can limit the domains from which your API-Key may be used, see [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

Answer (score 1):

In frontend build the keys will be bundled in JS code. The environment variables in frontend code gets replaced with their actual values during the build time. In server code you can just use environment variables and whenever you need to change the value, you don't have to rebuild the server, just restarting would pick up the new values from environment. That's not the case in frontend, so we have to set those keys in our source code only so that we can call the API.

Other way would be to have an API that returns the keys required on frontend, so that you can always return the updated values and don't have to deploy new builds. But again, devtools inspection would reveal the keys whenever used for any requests.

Only way to restrict the usage is to bind the domain for that token so that no other domains can call the api with same token. and for native mobile apps, you can create another token and use there.

Comment: Alright, I guess we will save it in our database and retrieve it and restrict its domain as it seems to be the best solution for what we're facing. Thank You!